# How to get the depth of the parse tree of a sentence produced by OpenNLP?

Tags: c#, depth, opennlp, parse-tree

How to get the depth of the parse tree of a sentence produced by OpenNLP?

I use c# OpenNLP for parsing a sentence and I have a functionthat generate the parse tree and return it.

An example sentence and corresponding parse tree is as follows:

```
THIS IS ANOTHER SIMPLE SENTENCE

(TOP (S (NP (DT THIS)) (VP (VBZ IS) (NP (DT ANOTHER) (NNP SIMPLE) (NN SENTENCE)))))
```

My problem is how to get the depth of the above tree?
Please refer the below image.[image]

In this case, the depth is 5  (starting from index 0)

Below is the c# code that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenNLP;
using OpenNLP.Tools.Parser;

namespace TextProcessing
{
    public class create_sentence_parsetree
    {

        public static string build_parse_tree(String str_sentence)
        {
            String str_parse_tree = "";
            EnglishTreebankParser parser = new EnglishTreebankParser("Modelspath/", true, false);
            OpenNLP.Tools.Parser.Parse sentenceParse = parser.DoParse(str_sentence);
            str_parse_tree = sentenceParse.Show().ToString();
            return str_parse_tree;
;
        }

    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can we get any information about the depth from the number of paranthesis?

Comment: You have GetChildren() and IsFlat(), so how would you get the depth of any kind of tree?

Comment: I have tried those. Can you provide me a code?